A little problem in combinatorics (to understand)
The text of an example in the textbook "A Path To Combinatorics" says

Claudia has cans of paint in eight different colors.
She wants to paint the four unit squares of a $2 x 2$ board in such a way that neighboring unit squares are painted in different colors.
Determine the number of distinct coloring schemes Claudia can make.
Two coloring schemes are considered the same if one can be obtained from the other by rotation.

SOLUTION :
We need at least two and at most four colors.
For the first ($2$ colors) and the last ($4$ colors) case , it is quite easy to understand why we have $\frac{P(8,2)}{2}$ and $\frac{P(8,4)}{4}$ different coloring schemes respectively
What I cannot understand, although the author of the textbook explains it, is :
Why in the third case ($3$ colors) the different coloring schemes are $\frac{P(8,3)}{2}$
Could somebody please elucidate me ?

It is your choice & decision to accept which-ever answer you want , no worries , though I am curious to know why you changed your accepted answer after so long.

Of course. although they (the answers) have helped me both . Today I was rereading the book and to clarify (again ) my doubts  I decided to reread the answers and I noticed the the other helped me more this time. but I really appreciate how much you have done to help me understand

In the three colour case, if the three colours chosen are $A,B,C$ chosen in $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$ ways with $n=8$, then one of the three will appear twice, so you have the possible patterns
A B    B C    C A       
C A    A B    B C   

and so there are $3 \times \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}6 = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}2$ possibilities.  All other patterns can be obtained by rotation.
Alternatively you can say the doubled colour can be chosen from $8$ and then $\frac{7 \times 6}{2}$  possibilities for the two single colours.

Board is like this :

2 Colour Case :
We have to choose 1 Colour for 1 & 4
We have to choose 1 Colour for 2 & 3
Rotation will make it $[8 \times 7] / 2$
4 Colour Case :
We have to choose 1 Colour each for 1 , 2 , 3 , 4
Rotation will make it $[8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5] / 4$
3 Colour Case :
We have to choose 1 Colour for 1 & 4
We have to choose 1 Colour for 2
We have to choose 1 Colour for 3
Rotation will make it $[8 \times 7 \times 6] / 2$
Due to exchanging 2 & 3 , there are 2 repetitions with rotation.
